# DrawerLayout hide another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

My main UI is hiding my Include UI. In first image you can see what i want. There are tabs in my UI and i want after that tabs, there should be one small UI will have details of it. So i created another small UI and include that in my main UI. My Main tab UI is hiding my Include UI. Please help me with it.

what i want in below image [image]

issue with my layout in below image

[image]

here is code for the same..

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:title="Test">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/containerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </FrameLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_nowplaying_card" ></include>

     </LinearLayout>
```

bottom_nowplaying_card code is below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/graybackcolor">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/slide_bottom_song_image"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/musicicon"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_songsdetails"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/slide_bottom_song_image"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/song_title_bar"
            style="@style/AppTheme"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Please select song"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/song_artist_bar"
            style="@style/AppTheme"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="sub Title"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/slide_bottom_song_image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bottom_songsdetails"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bottom_songsdetails">


        <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
            android:id="@+id/play_pause_bottom"
            android:layout_width="23dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:materialIcon="play"
            app:materialIconColor="?attr/iconColor"
            app:materialIconSize="35dp" />

        <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
            android:id="@+id/playlist"
            android:layout_width="23dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:materialIcon="playlist_plus"
            app:materialIconColor="?attr/iconColor"
            app:materialIconSize="35dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No change is required in bottom_nowplaying_card code

Consider replacing below xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/greencolor"
              android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                            android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/abc">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                               android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                               android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                                               app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                                               app:title="Test">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/containerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >


            </FrameLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                      android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
                                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                      android:layout_gravity="start"
                                                      android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
                                                      app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
                                                      app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
                                                      app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
                                                      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_nowplaying_card"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/abc"></include>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OR Try this**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/apptoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:title="Test">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:layout_below="@id/apptoolbar"
            android:layout_above="@id/include_layout">


        </FrameLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/bottom_nowplaying_card"
                 android:id="@+id/include_layout"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></include>

    </RelativeLayout>

<!--NavigationView as DrawerLayout’s drawer content view-->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigationdrawer_menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: getting below error. Error:(17, 68) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/abc'). Also why u commented NavigationView. I want that also. Sorry but i am new to android that why i am asking sily qus

Comment: its  include id... Please check the include tag.

Comment: Its there only. I just copied your code and past it. But getting same error. Dont know but its getting same error :(

Comment: Try using second one. Replace whole xml with it. Please be informed that backgrounds and colors I have used just for reference purpose. you can change them according to your project.

Comment: very helpfull. thank you so much... i just removed above id and it started working..

Answer (score 0):

`@Kushal Patil`  i found some Issues in your design i will tell u some changes...
  please try them

1. first of all in your **`Top XML`**

   ```
     <include layout="@layout/bottom_nowplaying_card" ></include>
   ```

   This line of code add below  **FrameLayout** closing  `ok`
   and

   ```
   frame layout's height  should be   wrap_content .
   ```
2. now in your **`second XML`**  update from top of xml to my below code

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/topContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/colorGrey">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

   <---paste your content here..........ok --->

       </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

now if you face any problem comment on it. and 
 if Helpfull for you Don't forgot to **`accept`** it.